# Can't get correct number formatting as a string

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, number-formatting, swift-playground

I've developed a custom control for money input, which contains `UITextField` and `UILabel`. When the user taps on it, it becomes active and switches to the `UITextField` for data input and accepts only numbers and dot symbol, when the user finishes editing it becomes passive and switches to `UILabel` just to show formatted money value. But there is one little issue which I'm unable to fix a lot of days already.

Let's say the user writes down `88.99` and presses done, this becomes `"$ 88.99"` in a `UILabel`, next when the user again taps on it to edit the initial value I get the following value `"88.98999999999999"`. To not present the entire code I selected the core part in a playground format which gives the same result as in my complete project:

```
extension NumberFormatter {
    static public func defaultCurrencyFormatter() -> NumberFormatter {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.currencySymbol = ""
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.currencyGroupingSeparator = ","
        formatter.currencyDecimalSeparator = "."
        return formatter
    }
}

let stringValue = NumberFormatter.defaultCurrencyFormatter().number(from: "88.99")?.stringValue

print(stringValue) // result is Optional("88.98999999999999")
```

I have no idea why using this NumberFormatter I get such a result. I was thinking that explicitly setting `minimumFractionDigits` and `maximumFractionDigits` will solve my issue but it does not affect my result

Comment: Actually both `minimumFractionDigits` and `maximumFractionDigits` affect the behavior to format **numbers**, the opposite what you are doing. `stringValue` is related to `NSNumber` not to `NumberFormatter`

Comment: You might want to set this value to true: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter/1410503-generatesdecimalnumbers

Comment: If there is no currency symbol you should simply use `.decimal` style.

Answer (score 0):

`NumberFormatter` is legacy from objc and it operates with `NSNumber`/`CGFloat` etc. and usually it is helpful for localized text formatting. Much powerful and convenient parser for numbers is `Scanner` but if you don't have complex data structure to parse and don't want to deal with `Floating-point error mitigation` just use swift's `Float`:

```swift
// Float from string
if let float = Float("88.99") {
    print(float)
    
    // String from float
    let text = String(float)
    print(text)
}

Prints:

88.99
88.99
```

Comment: I don't think Float is large enough to keep large money values that can hold Double. In this case, it might lose some parts. I know, ideally, I should use decimal, but this is a legacy project and it will take big time to refactor

Comment: @JunoQuantum Agreed, Double is preferred.

Comment: @JunoQuantum You should use Swift `Decimal` type. And make sure to use the `Decimal(string:)` initializer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
extension String {
    var currencyStyle: String? {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
        formatter.groupingSize = 3
        formatter.currencyGroupingSeparator = ","
        formatter.currencyDecimalSeparator = "."

        if let double = Double(self) {
            let number = NSNumber(value: double)
            return formatter.string(from: number)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

to use it:

```
    let str = "12388.98999999999999".currencyStyle
    print(str) // Optional("12,388.99")
```

Comment: No need to coerce the double to NSNumber. You can use Formatter's method `string(for: Any)` and pass your double. Note that this will create a new number formatter every time the user changes the field value.